# Объединить два DF по разным типам даты

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Итак, есть первый DF:

```
      Data Set
28.01.2010  x1
20.03.2011  x1
09.05.2012  x1
29.06.2013  x1
19.08.2014  x1
09.10.2015  x1
24.02.2008  x2
26.06.2009  x2
27.10.2010  x2
27.02.2012  x2
29.06.2013  x2
30.10.2014  x2
```

И второй DF:

```
Data   Set Val
2010    x1  5
2011    x1  6
2012    x1  4
2013    x1  6
2014    x1  5
2015    x1  5
2016    x1  8
2007    x2  4
2008    x2  5
2009    x2  6
2010    x2  5
2011    x2  5
2012    x2  4
2013    x2  5
2014    x2  4
```

Нужно объединить по первому типу даты, главное : совпадение по году, то есть на выходе хотим получить:

```
Data       Set  Val
28.01.2010  x1  5
20.03.2011  x1  6
09.05.2012  x1  4
29.06.2013  x1  6
19.08.2014  x1  5
09.10.2015  x1  5
24.02.2008  x2  5
26.06.2009  x2  6
27.10.2010  x2  5
27.02.2012  x2  4
29.06.2013  x2  5
30.10.2014  x2  4
```

Comment: какие типы данных в первом DF: `print(df1.dtypes)`?

Comment: я еще не забивал в python, просто в экселе исходные данные

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `d1.Data` имеет тип данных `datetime`:

```
In [97]: d1.dtypes
Out[97]:
Data    datetime64[ns]  # <---
Set             object
dtype: object
```

решение:

```
In [67]: d1 = d1.assign(Year=d1.Data.dt.year)

In [70]: res = d1.merge(d2.rename(columns={'Data':'Year'})).drop('Year', axis=1)
```

результат:

```
In [71]: res
Out[71]:
         Data Set  Val
0  2010-01-28  x1    5
1  2011-03-20  x1    6
2  2012-09-05  x1    4
3  2013-06-29  x1    6
4  2014-08-19  x1    5
5  2015-09-10  x1    5
6  2008-02-24  x2    5
7  2009-06-26  x2    6
8  2010-10-27  x2    5
9  2012-02-27  x2    4
10 2013-06-29  x2    5
11 2014-10-30  x2    4
```

Comment: Тип даты : datetime64

Comment: Не знаю из -за этого ли (`drop('Year', axis=1)` , но у меня пропал столбец с датами. Хотя у меня изначать `YEAR` был

Comment: @Max52, нет, `drop('Year', axis=1)` - удаляет столбец `Year`. Вы пробовали протестировать решение на данных из вопроса?

Comment: Да, все работает, благодарю